# Target child element of parent on click using Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to create accordion using Vanilla JS, but I don't know how, I'm stucked.

My problem is I can't target class "accordion-text" but inside **clicked**  element with class "accordion".

I've tried using querySelector but that's only for first element, and my toggle 
works only for first class.

If you click on Accordion 2, 3, 4 you will see only 1. Accordion toggling.

https://jsfiddle.net/ntcywngo/12/

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h1>ACCORDION 1</h1>
    <div class="accordion-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
    <h1>ACCORDION 2</h1>
    <div class="accordion-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
    <h1>ACCORDION 3</h1>
    <div class="accordion-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
    <h1>ACCORDION 4</h1>
    <div class="accordion-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
    <h1>ACCORDION 5</h1>
    <div class="accordion-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.accordion {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.accordion-text {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  top: 35px;
  z-index: 100;
}

 .active-accordion-text { 
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
  }
```

JS:

```
var accordionElements = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion');

for (var i = 0; i < accordionElements.length; i++) {
    accordionElements.item(i).addEventListener('click', function () {
        document.querySelector('.accordion-text').classList.toggle('active-accordion-text');
   });

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be with `document.querySelector`.It will always select the first matched element from the dom.Replaced it with `this.querySelector`

```js
var accordionElements = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion');

for (var i = 0; i < accordionElements.length; i++) {
  accordionElements.item(i).addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.querySelector('.accordion-text').classList.toggle('active-accordion-text');
  });

};
```

```css
.accordion {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.accordion-text {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  top: 35px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.active-accordion-text {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: auto;
  top: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <h1>ACCORDION 1</h1>
  <div class="accordion-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
  <h1>ACCORDION 2</h1>
  <div class="accordion-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
  <h1>ACCORDION 3</h1>
  <div class="accordion-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
  <h1>ACCORDION 4</h1>
  <div class="accordion-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
  <h1>ACCORDION 5</h1>
  <div class="accordion-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```